# ¿Cómo reutilizar un componente ya creado pero modificar algunas etiquetas "Angular"?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, binding, componentes

Estoy intentando reutilizar componentes que ya están creados por mis colegas, tengo un ejemplo de un componente llamado "Crear usuario", y yo estoy realizando el componente de "Editar usuario", deberían tener el mismo formato por lo tanto quiero reutilizar el formato, solo que en "Editar usuario", algunos input deben estar en "disabled", pero si lo modifico desde el componente de "Crear usuario", estaría modificando todos los módulos que están utilizando ese componente. La opción que tenía en mente era copiar absolutamente todo el HTML de "crear usuario" y pegarlo en "editar usuario", solo que un poco modificado. ¿Hacer esto sería mala práctica?, cómo podría evitar la copia de código y modificar solamente algunos campos?

Comment: Esta es una pregunta basada en opiniones. Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Te recomendaría que leyeras sobre la filosofía de componentes en Angular. Encontré un video que quizás te pueda orientar en la dirección correcta. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGKRKDPGUSs La idea de los componentes es justamente que sean reutilizables. Si no puedes reutilizar un componente, seguramente éste tenga muchas responsabilidades y sea demasiado grande. Quizás la solución sea dividir el componente en otros más pequeños que te ayuden a crear uno nuevo reutilizando otros mas chicos

Comment: Muchas gracias!, con el manejo de componentes entre bindings pude solucionar y aprender mejor!